# Define variables in document so that macro definition goes into preamble

Tags: macros, preamble, variable

I've written some macros to add OMR characters to the generated document. The OMR characters are needed for an envelope inserter machine.

When I want to print OMR characters for a double-sided document, I have to put:

```
 \DoubleSidedPrinting
 \AddOMR
```

I want to put my macro in a preamble that will be precompiled and be reused for several documents. In that case, I will only have to set DoubleSidedPrinting and AddOMR in each document. But this doesn't work. Do you know a workaround?

```
% The goal is to put this code in a reusable preamble
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newif\ifAddOMR
\def\AddOMR{\AddOMRtrue}
\def\OmitOMR{\AddOMRfalse}

\newif\ifDoubleSidedPrinting
\def\SingleSidedPrinting{\DoubleSidedPrintingfalse}
\def\DoubleSidedPrinting{\DoubleSidedPrintingtrue}

%\SingleSidedPrinting               %%if I define SingleSidedPrinting (or DoubleSidedPrinting) on this line
\DoubleSidedPrinting                %%the code is working
\AddOMR                             %%if I define SingleSidedPrinting (or DoubleSidedPrinting) on this line
%\OmitOMR                           %%the code is working

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LastOddCheck}{
    \ifodd\value{page}
        \if@filesw
            \immediate\write\@auxout{
                \gdef\string\LastOddPage{\the\value{page}}
            }
        \fi 
    \fi
}
\newcommand*{\LastOddPage}{0}

\ifAddOMR
    \ClearShipoutPicture
    \AddToShipoutPicture{
        \ifDoubleSidedPrinting
            \ifodd\c@page 
                \LastOddCheck
                \ifnum\LastOddPage=\value{page}
                    \put(11,503){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                    \put(11,489.5){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                    \put(11,475){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                \else
                    \put(11,503){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                    \put(11,475){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                \fi
            \else
            \fi
        \else
            \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=\value{page}
                    \put(11,503){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                    \put(11,489.5){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                    \put(11,475){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
            \else
                \put(11,503){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                \put(11,475){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}} 
            \fi
        \fi
    }
    \makeatother
\else
\fi

\ifDoubleSidedPrinting
    \AtEndDocument{\cleardoublepage}
\else
\fi

% This will be the end of the reusable preamble

%\SingleSidedPrinting               %%I would like to define SingleSidedPrinting (or DoubleSidedPrinting) only at this moment
%\DoubleSidedPrinting               %%but if I do so, the code is not working. Is there a workaround?

\begin{document}

\newpage  %% page 1
\mbox{Text on page 1}

\newpage  %% page 2
\mbox{Text on page 2}

\newpage  %% page 3
\mbox{Text on page 3}

\newpage  %% page 4
\mbox{Text on page 4}

%\newpage  %% page 5
%\mbox{Text on page 5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking. Can you provide an example of what you got, compared to what you were expecting?

Comment: The goal is to put the code between \documentclass and \begin{document} in a preamble that will be reused among several tex files. But in that case I won't be able to define the variables before I'm using them in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\ifAddOMR` and `\ifDoubleSidedPrinting` tests are evaluated too early, since you want to use `\SingleSidedPrinting`, `\DoubleSidedPrinting`, `\AddOMR` or `\OmitOMR` after the tests have been performed. The solution is to delay testing of the flags by putting the tests+decoration code inside a macro that is expanded *after* you set the flags, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newif\ifAddOMR
\def\AddOMR{\AddOMRtrue}
\def\OmitOMR{\AddOMRfalse}

\newif\ifDoubleSidedPrinting
\def\SingleSidedPrinting{\DoubleSidedPrintingfalse}
\def\DoubleSidedPrinting{\DoubleSidedPrintingtrue}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LastOddCheck}{
    \ifodd\value{page}
        \if@filesw
            \immediate\write\@auxout{
                \gdef\string\LastOddPage{\the\value{page}}
            }
        \fi
    \fi
}
\newcommand*{\LastOddPage}{0}

\newcommand*{\myLayoutDependentAdditions}{%
  \ifAddOMR
      \ClearShipoutPicture
      \AddToShipoutPicture{
          \ifDoubleSidedPrinting
              \ifodd\c@page
                  \LastOddCheck
                  \ifnum\LastOddPage=\value{page}
                      \put(11,503){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                      \put(11,489.5){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                      \put(11,475){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                  \else
                      \put(11,503){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                      \put(11,475){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                  \fi
              \else
              \fi
          \else
              \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=\value{page}
                      \put(11,503){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                      \put(11,489.5){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                      \put(11,475){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
              \else
                  \put(11,503){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
                  \put(11,475){\linethickness{0.5mm}{\line(1,0){17}}}
              \fi
          \fi
      }
  \else
  \fi

  \ifDoubleSidedPrinting
      \AtEndDocument{\cleardoublepage}
  \else
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% This will be the end of the reusable preamble

\SingleSidedPrinting
\AddOMR
\myLayoutDependentAdditions

\begin{document}

\newpage  %% page 1
\mbox{Text on page 1}

\newpage  %% page 2
\mbox{Text on page 2}

\newpage  %% page 3
\mbox{Text on page 3}

\newpage  %% page 4
\mbox{Text on page 4}

%\newpage  %% page 5
%\mbox{Text on page 5}

\end{document}
```

Also note that I moved the `\makeatother` down, because we want to do it unconditionally (in *all cases,* whatever flags are set).